# Correct way to import SpreadJS Charting library in an angular application

Tags: angular, spreadjs

I'm trying to import the SpreadJS charting library in my angular application but no matter the options I try I never get results. A colleague, however, using the same code and setup, is able to use the charts correctly.

The versions we're using are:

```
    "@grapecity/spread-excelio": "^12.0.9",
    "@grapecity/spread-sheets": "^12.0.9",
    "@grapecity/spread-sheets-angular": "^12.0.9",
    "@grapecity/spread-sheets-charts": "^12.0.9",
```

installed via NPM modules.

We also tries the following guide but it seems out of date and doesn't work for us:
https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/create-angular-spreadsheets-with-angular-cli

The way we use them in the components is by importing them like this:

```
import * as GC from '@grapecity/spread-sheets';
import '@grapecity/spread-sheets-charts';
```

When I call `sheet.charts.clear();` I get the following error message:
`Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined` (assume sheet is a variable holding a reference to a spreadjs sheet).
My colleague has no issues with the same code and the charts load perfectly for him.

Any suggestions in what else we should try?

Comment: First. If you use `angular.json` for importing scripts of `index.html` you don't have to import your library in components then (this approach is usually used when old libraries are used that are not split into modules). Also it would be great if you provided us some small working example in StackBlitz

Comment: I finally figured out that this issue was caused by the package-lock.json. I deleted this file and node_modules and it started working "magically"

Comment: @Narshe write this as an answer and I will upvote it. I'm currently taking a close look at SpreadJS.

Comment: @SQLGeorge done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this was happening to us is that we had different versions for each module in our `package-lock.json`.

In order to fix it, we simply deleted the **`package-lock.json`** and the **node-modules** folder. After running `npm install` again, everything started to work fine. Just make sure that the `package.json` also contains the same version for each of the modules.